# Using instance field in super() in class constructor

Tags: java

I have 2 classes:

```
public abstract class SuperClass() {
    public SuperClass(Class1 prop1, Class2, prop2, Class3 prop3) {
        this.prop1 = prop1;
        this.prop2 = prop2;
        this.prop3 = prop3;
    }
}
```

```
public abstract class ChildClass() extends SuperClass(){
    public ChildClass(Class1 prop1) {
        super(prop1, prop1.someMethod1(), prop1.someMethod2());
    }
}
```

I want to add new **non-static** field to the ChildClass, and use it in constructor like below:

```
public abstract class ChildClass() extends SuperClass(){
    private Map<String, String> newProp = ...;
    public ChildClass(Class1 prop1) {
        super(prop1, newProp.get("some_string"), newProp.get("some_string"));
    }
}
```

Is it possible to do this, because it throws "Cannot Reference “X” Before Supertype Constructor Has Been Called". Also newProp should be non-static

Comment: The error message already tells you it is not possible to do this, so why ask if it is possible to do this?! You will need to find another way to perform this initialization.

Comment: BTW `newProp`  will not even be empty when `super()` is being called, it actually would not even be initialized since the *local* instance initialization would only start **after** the super class is initialized (*probably* the reason for not allowing such)

Comment: Even if you have `private Map<String, String> newProp = Map.of("a","1", "b","2");` the *initialization* of `newProp` field is moved to each constructor *after* its `super` call. So at the time of calling `super(.., newProp.get("some_string"), ..)` the `newProp` doesn't hold yet `Map.of("a","1", "b","2")` but `null`. This means you would end up with NPE because you end up with `null.get("some_string")`. That is why it is an error to try using fields in `super(..)`.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to add new **non-static** field to the ChildClass, and use it in constructor like below: [...]

No, you cannot do that.  The superclass is initialized before the subclass's instance variables are initialized, regardless of how the particular superclass constructor and its arguments are chosen, so your non-static field does not have its value yet at the time you propose to use it.

However, you should be able to obtain a similar result by giving the subclass a static factory method and a constructor designed to be used with it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the call to the super constructor must be the first statement in the `ChildClass` constructor, and `this` cannot be referenced at this point.

It is somewhat hacky, but the solution might be to use a static `ThreadLocal` in order to temporarily store the value of 'newProp' in a static context, before storing it as an attribute in the newly created object

```java
abstract class ChildClass extends SuperClass{
    
    private static ThreadLocal<Map<String, String>> tmpNewProp = new ThreadLocal<>();
    
    private static Map<String, String> newPropInit() {
        if(tmpNewProp.get() == null) {
            tmpNewProp.set(...); // <-- instantiate newProp here
        }
        return tmpNewProp.get();
    }
    
    private Map<String, String> newProp;
    
    public ChildClass(Class1 prop1) {
       super(prop1, newPropInit().get("some_string"), newPropInit().get("some_string"));
       this.newProp = newPropInit();
    }
}
```